# How do I display a succes message after this forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In this script I'm checking a list of css files for syntax errors:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var rework = require('rework');
var expand = require ('glob-expand');
var conformance = require('rework-suit-conformance');

var files = expand({
  filter: 'isFile',
  cwd: 'build/'
}, ['**/*.css']);

files.forEach(function (file) {
  var css = fs.readFileSync('build/' + file, 'utf-8');
  try {
    rework(css).use(conformance);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log( chalk.red('Error in: ' + 'build/' + file) );
    console.log( chalk.red(e) );
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

If the foreach loop finishes without errors, I would like to display a succes message:

```
console.log( chalk.green('Done, without errors.') );
```

But where would I place that? What would be the correct way? I could place it at the end of the file, which wouldn't be reached on an error, but that doesn't feel quite right..

Comment: Keep count of each successful iteration. If that counter === files.length, then do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is safe to put it `after` the `forEach`. Besides, if there were errors, it would exit before `forEach` finishes. If the `forEach` finished, it's safe to say all went well.

```
files.forEach(function (file) {
  var css = fs.readFileSync('build/' + file, 'utf-8');
  try {
    rework(css).use(conformance);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log( chalk.red('Error in: ' + 'build/' + file) );
    console.log( chalk.red(e) );
    // If any error happened, this should kill everything before proceeding
    process.exit(1);
  }
});

// If all went well, it should reach this code.
console.log( chalk.green('Done, without errors.') );
```

Comment: That's true. So there are no real downsides to doing that? It feels a little wrong to not encapsulate it in a function or a callback or something.

Comment: @Sam Well, it sounds too simple (and lots of things go wrong with simple). But yeah, if the app gets "killed" when an error happens, then there's absolutely no way it can reach the end of the `forEach`. If it does, no errors happened. Thus we can safely say it is a success.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a counter variable just before the forEach begins. After the catch block, put the following: Every time an iteration completes successfully, decrement the counter. Check if counter is zero - If yes, console.log('Success')

```
var fc = files.length;

files.forEach(function (file) {
  var css = fs.readFileSync('build/' + file, 'utf-8');
  try {
    rework(css).use(conformance);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log( chalk.red('Error in: ' + 'build/' + file) );
    console.log( chalk.red(e) );
    process.exit(1);
  }

  fc -= 1;
  if (fc === 0) {
  console.log('Success');
  }
});
```